# show detail processlist like at mariadb on maxscale

Tags: session, mariadb, maxscale

on mariadb when i need check what are query is running or sleep on mariadb instance. i can see with `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or `select * information_schema.processlist`.

But after mariadb join and client connect to maxscale i can't see processlist like `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or `select * information_schema.processlist`

so how to check query session if mariadb is already join to maxscale ?

this is configuration maxscale

```
[maxscale] 
threads=auto 
max_auth_errors_until_block=0 
admin_host=192.168.101.107 
admin_port=8989 
admin_enabled=1
```

any advice ?

Edit. I already update paramater at maxscale configuration

```
[maxscale]
threads=auto
max_auth_errors_until_block=0
admin_host=192.168.101.107
admin_port=8989
admin_enabled=1
retain_last_statements=20
dump_last_statements=on_error
```

query already show from command

```
maxctrl show sessions
```

but there is query from last execution on each session. and i can't see the different like sleep or still running when i run command `SHOW PROCESSLIST` on mariadb.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCOXa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The output of `maxctrl list sessions` should display the latest query that each session executed if you have [`retain_last_statements`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-24-mariadb-maxscale-configuration-guide/#retain_last_statements) enabled (at the time of writing, there is [an open bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MXS-3037) for this behavior that is being investigated).

MaxScale currently only displays the latest query executed for each session, not each active query. This seems like something that can be quite easily added so I'd recommend opening a feature request on the MariaDB Jira under the MaxScale project.

Comment: i already add the configuration but still confused because i can't see the different process like when i run command `SHOW PROCESSLIST`